# Before Github commit: What's your housekeeping rules for file management?

Tags: git, github, version-control, file-management

I just finish my first python project and going to Gitbash upload to Github, only then I found the files are in a mess in the project folders: test.json, test2.csv, try.py...
I come up with two ideas:

> 1. delete the unnecessary files (the risk is that maybe a file name test.json is actually referred by the main code)
> 2. add .gitignore (invest more time on keeping junk files?)

Would you please share your insight: how you manage your dev files? naming, structuring etc.
How do you keep the folder clean and efficient for each commit?
Thanks the community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, write a `.gitignore` and keep it up to date. A programmer's job is to teach the computer to do rote tasks, they're better at it. Avoiding accidentally committing junk is a rote task.

Without a maintained `.gitignore` every time you commit you have to check you're committing only the right things. You have to be careful every time, and humans are bad at that. With a maintained `.gitignore` you, and anyone else who might work on the project, can safely `git add .`.

A little discipline will make the job easier. Rather than littering the project root with test and temp files, use a temp directory and ignore that. You can also ignore things like `test.*`, `try.*`, and `*.tmp`.

---

That you have a bunch of `test` and `try` files suggests your tests are not automated. Automated tests are another way to keep your project clean and avoid having to be careful. When your tests are automated, you don't need to write little throw away test files and programs.

Comment: Thank you! Good idea to keep those in test folders, and next I will google how to automated testing~ cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can find file structure in [this guide](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure)

for [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)
and git [commit message](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/)

if want to recommit and organize you commits:

```sh
git log # show commits history
```

```sh
git reset --soft <you first commit "SHA-1 hash">
```

```sh
git push origin -f
```